# Problems accessing Service Fabric Explorer and Cluster via RDP

Tags: azure-devops, azure-service-fabric, azure-pipelines, azure-virtual-machine, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have an infrastructure pipeline in Azure DevOps that setup a service fabric cluster. The fabric cluster's key vault and certificate are generated by a custom PowerShell script I wrote, while the cluster and its resources are generated by an ARM template. They are executed as tasks in the pipeline.

However, I am having problems accessing the generated fabric cluster via Service Fabric Explorer using web address: https://myclustername.mylocation.cloudapp.azure.com:19080/Explorer 
[image]
I also have problem accessing the nodes using RDP:

[image]

I tried the following:

Restarted virtual machine scale set.
Checked the ports are open on load balancer: 3389-3391
I don't get this problem if I setup the fabric resource group with visual studio.

I checked the certificate generated and made sure it has a subject that is the same as the fabric cluster url. Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: According to the two error screenshots, the issue seemed all belong to connection issue instead of a very normal certificate verified issue. Does the script you used in visual studio is same with in Azure Devops pipeline? Please also refer to this github issue: https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/1132

Comment: Hi Merlin, thanks for your reply. I tried the latest ARM template from github and it worked. The one I was using before was the VS2017 template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I used the ARM template that came with visual studio 2017. The template is old (2016). I updated the template to the recent one and the issue is resolved:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/service-fabric-secure-cluster-5-node-1-nodetype

I still have some problem for adding a custom internal load balancer, but all the other resources out of the ARM template are working.

Comment: Glad to hear! Thanks for this solution shared. Please accept this answer after two days thus other SO user who meet this same issue can refer to this solution:-)

Comment: Thanks Merlin, I have other service fabric related questions are you able to help?

Comment: of course sure. Just raise the question here, then I could help with you(this method can also let you get more help from SO others suggestion). The issue about custome load balancer?

Comment: Thanks Merlin, the load balancer issue is resolved now. The other issue is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58056392/service-fabric-service-discovery-without-port-number

Comment: This question is a bit broad

Comment: Using reverse proxy in service fabric

Comment: Got it. I will pay attention to give you some suggestion about that~:-)